# Display large number of records from Postgresql Table in batches using Psycopg2 cursors and Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to query a table with 10 Million rows using Psycopg2 with Flask.

I want to retrieve say 100 records at a time using cursor.itersize.

My question is when I retrieve the first 100 and pass it onto a template like:

```
with conn.cursor(name='custom_cursor') as cursor:
    cursor.itersize = 100  # chunk size
    postgreSQL_select_Query = "SELECT * FROM public.table"
    cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)

    first_set = cursor.fetchall()

    return render_template('View Records.html', first_set=first_set)
```

Now how do I get back to where I left off efficiently? I want to be able to redirect users with a **Next Page** button in `View Records.html` and skip the first 100 rows to display records 101-200 and so on.

From what I could find online, I understand that offset is an ineffective solution. Tried it out myself and does seem time consuming.

Comment: Problems with above; 1) Expecting a user to scroll through 10 million records. 2) Your use of `'itersize`. You will be returning all the rows using codes as shown. Read this section [Server side cursors](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors). Short version `itersize` controls  batch size  when a cursor is iterated over not as a `LIMIT` on total records returned.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver, so it's going to be filtered geographically depending on the user's location. So will probably add a where clause to the query. I see your point about itersize. Do you have any suggestions as to how I could go about this?

Comment: Use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`. My guess is there will be more time taken in displaying the data then in fetching it.